# json loop values using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops

i have the below json object and I want to loop inside the result:

```
{
  "result":
    [
      {
        "uid": "4efd59257641f",
        "name": "Jack",
        "email": "asd@gmail.com",
        "phone": null,
        "state": null,
        "zip": null
      }
    ]
}
```

I am using the below:

```
$.each(result, function(key,value) {
    uid= value.uid;
    name= value.name;
    email= value.email;
    phone= value.phone; // same stuff for state and zip
});
```

I want to find the length of the number of name=value pairs in result and loop based on that. Can it be done?

Like in the above json response:
**result has 6 elements (uid, name, email, phone, state, zip).
i want to loop 6 times and get its corresponding element**.

Comment: This `each` statement will go through all 6 elements in result

Comment: @Diode: But I dont want to access elements using their names (like uid, name and so on..) I want to access them like, result.[firstelement] -- something like that

Comment: @KannanLg: It's difficult to understand what you want. Are you saying that you want a collection where the `name` is used as the key that references the assocaited object?

Comment: i want a loop like 

for (values in results){

//get all the values(uid, name, email....) here by looping)
key[i];

//key[0] -> uid
//key[1] -> name
and so on
}

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://jsfiddle.net/Tv2fw/ (Or http://jsfiddle.net/Tv2fw/1/)

Comment: @KannanLg: Well, you already know how to use `$.each`, so... And making the text in your question **bold** doesn't make it any more *clear*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OP was looking for was a way reference the current object's key while constructing another value (in my example it's a string, but it could be something else I suppose). A `for` loop of the object works (and an `$.each()` as well) on the `value` passed to the anonymous function in the first `$.each()` loop.

**`for` loop:**

```
var result = {
  "result":
    [
      {
        "uid": "4efd59257641f",
        "name": "Jack",
        "email": "asd@gmail.com",
        "phone": null,
        "state": null,
        "zip": null
      },
      {
        "uid": "kdflsjkdf",
        "name": "Bill",
        "email": "abablabba@example.com"
      }
    ]
};

$.each(result.result, function(key, value) {
    var str = '';
    for (k in value) {
        str += k + ' = ' + value[k] + '; ';
    }
    console.log(str);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tv2fw/2/

**`$.each()` loop:**

```
var result = {
  "result":
    [
      {
        "uid": "4efd59257641f",
        "name": "Jack",
        "email": "asd@gmail.com",
        "phone": null,
        "state": null,
        "zip": null
      },
      {
        "uid": "kdflsjkdf",
        "name": "Bill",
        "email": "abablabba@example.com"
      }
    ]
};

$.each(result.result, function(key, value) {
    var str = '';
    $.each(value, function (k, v) {
        str += k + ' = ' + v + '; ';
    });
    console.log(str);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tv2fw/5/

Answer (score 1):

you can loop through it like that:

```
var counter = 0;
for(key in j['result'][0]){
    alert(key +' => '+j['result'][0][key]);
    ++counter;
}
alert(counter);
```

Comment: yes, that did work, thanks, can i include their corresponding values in this for loop as well?

Comment: Why do a `for` loop to count, then another loop to construct? This is a confusing question.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I didnt want 2 loops. I didnt know how to write that each loop. you fiddler is exactly what I am looking for. thanks. it worked. pls post as answer

Comment: @KannanLg - I was just pointing out the obvious that counting the object elements in one loop to use to iterate in another loop didn't make any sense. This example demonstrates what the *question* was asking explicitly, but didn't answer the underlying problem you were actually concered with (but didn't know how to ask).

Answer (score 0):

What you require is not clear. But seeing your comment, I think that you need array based result. So you can use the following structure.

```
var response = {
  "result":
    [
      [ "4efd59257641f", "Jack", "asd@gmail.com", null, null, null ],
      [ "4efd52357641f", "Jack1", "asd1@gmail.com", null, null, null ]
      [ "4efd23257641f", "Jack2", "asd2@gmail.com", null, null, null ]
    ]
}
```

So you will be able to loop like

```
$.each(response.result, function(key,value) {
    uid= value[0];
    name= value[1];
    email= value[2];
    phone= value[3]; // same stuff for state and zip
});
```

Or

```
for(var i=0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
       var value = response.result[i];
       uid= value[0];
       name= value[1];
       email= value[2];
       phone= value[3]; // same stuff for state and zip
}
```

Comment: If it's possible to have `x or more` number of data elements for an entry, using a key name to identify that data relationship is useful. I believe this may be the ultimate objective of the OP (irregardless of the `null` values in the example).

Comment: Yes you are correct. That is the correct way to do it. I just wanted to know whether this is what he needs.